# Is it possible to pass alert messages through an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

Basically, I have a document management system sitting in an iFrame on my website. When you directly open the DMS and have unsaved changes to your document, an alert message is displayed saying that this is the case and if you are sure to leave the website. However, when I change properties of the document via iFrame and close my webpage, this message does not display.

Is there any method to pass alerts through or how would one manage this problem?

Comment: You mean the onunload script in the page is not triggered when the page is in an iframe?

Comment: Exactly! But the onUnload is generally only triggered, when there are unsaved changes to the document

Comment: [Have a look at some of these](https://www.google.com/search?q=onunload+iframe+site:stackoverflow.com)